# Add +1 to Count=0 if element in list has at least one 1 value. Python

Tags: python, list, count, addition

```
count_element_has_1 = 0
count_all_0 = 0   

my_list = [[0,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]
```

i want to check if each element of the list has at least 1 then add +1 to count_element_has_1 and if they are all 0 then add +1 to count_all_0

so in this case it would look like

```
count_element_has_1 = 2
count_all_0 = 1
```

Comment: the only way i know how to do is to add it for each value of 1 and that's not what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for lst in my_list:
    if 1 in lst:
       count_element_has_1 += 1
    elif lst.count(0) == len(lst):
       count_all_0 += 1
```

Depending on the lists, the second condition might be better to do something like:

```
elif all(x==0 for x in lst):
    count_all_0 += 1
```

Since that allows for short-circuiting.

Comment: +1, Alternatively, in horrific one-liner mode: `count_element_has_1, count_all_0 = map(sum, zip(*((1 in l, all(i == 0 for i in l)) for l in my_list)))`

Comment: @Lattyware -- I'm not sure whether to be impressed, or to throw my laptop at you ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `sum` function, combined with list comprehensions.

If the lists can contain *other* numbers than `0` and `1`, try this:

```
count_has_1 = sum(1 for element in my_list if 1 in element)
count_all_0 = sum(1 for element in my_list if all(e == 0 for e in element))
```

If you know *for sure* that the lists contain *only* `0` and `1`, you could also do this:

```
count_has_1 = sum(map(any, my_list))
count_all_0 = len(my_list) - count_has_1
```

The first line is using the fact that Python interprets `1` and `0` as `True` and `False`, and vice versa, by first mapping each sublist to whether any of the values is true, e.g. `[0,1,0] -> True`, and then summing up the resulting list of booleans, e.g. `[True, False, True] -> 2`.

Comment: As a note, this does mean multiple loops, which isn't as good, performance-wise.

Comment: @tobias_k ``count_has_1 = sum(1 in element for element in my_list)`` works

Comment: @eyquem Ah, right. The magic of interpreting integers as booleans, and booleans as integers... how about this one? `count_has_1 = sum(map(any, my_list))` (assuming all numbers are either `1` or `0`).

Comment: @tobias_k I think it's perfect. Non-zero elements don't have even to be only digits 1. I think you should rewrite your answer with only: ``count_has_1 = sum(map(any, my_list))`` and ``count_all_0 = len(my_list) - count_has_1`` and then I would upvote it and ask @dracontheOry to accept it !

Comment: @eyquem Edited. Still, we should keep the case for other numbers than 0 and 1, as otherwise a list like `[0,2,3]` would be counted towards `count_has_1` as well.

Comment: @Lattyware Just wondering: Isn't the amount of work the same in mgilson's Python loop, your brillantly-horrific one-liner and my two sums? It's either one loop counting two things, or two loops counting one thing per iteration.

Comment: @tobias_k Doing two loops is a lot more effort computationally.

Comment: @tobias_k ``sum(1 for element in my_list if 1 in element)`` is ``sum(1 in element for element in my_list)`` - And ``sum(1 for element in my_list if all(e == 0 for e in element))`` is ``sum(not any(element) for element in my_list)``

Comment: @eyquem I know that. I wanted to keep the first solution simple and free of integer-boolean-magic.

Comment: @Lattyware Could you please explain? In my view, in all three cases the same work is done: _n_ times the `1 in sublist` check, plus _n_ times the `all(...)` check, _n_ being the length of the list.

Comment: @tobias_k You are forgetting that iterating over a list is a computationally expensive task. There is overhead from iterating over the list, and your method involves twice as much.

Comment: @tobias_k Always considering that certain things are magic programs the mind to not remind them as commonly usable.

Comment: @Lattyware You have a point. I just did some timing tests... mgilson's simple Python loop is indeed roughly twice as fast as both your one-liner and my two sums, which are about the same. (`sum(map(any, my_list))` is fastest, but that doesn't count.) Wouldn't have thought so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter()`, `O(N^2)` complexity:

```
In [22]: lis=[[0,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]

In [23]: from collections import Counter

In [24]: count_element_has_1 = 0

In [25]: count_all_0 = 0

In [26]: for x in lis:
    c=Counter(x)
    if c[0]==len(x):
        count_all_0 +=1
    elif c[1]>0:    
        count_element_has_1 +=1
   ....:         

In [27]: count_element_has_1
Out[27]: 2

In [28]: count_all_0
Out[28]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [[0,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0],[4,0,88]]
#
count_has_1 = sum(1 in sub for sub in my_list)
print count_has_1 # prints 2
#
count_all_0 = sum(not any(sub) for sub in my_list)
print count_all_0 # prints 1
```

.

If there are only 0 and 1 in the sublists, it's useless to count the two categories:

```
my_list = [[0,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]
#
count_has_non0 = sum(map(any,my_list))
print count_has_non0 # prints 2
#
print len(my_list) - count_has_1  # prints 1
```